# How to exclude rows from a table where a certain flag YES is same for all the months for a given ID

Tags: mysql

I've a table with 4 columns and I want to exclude all the IDs where Appointment = Yes for all the dates.

**Table (18 rows)**

```
ID, DateYM, Status, Appointment
1,  2021-01-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-02-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-03-01, Off, Yes
1,  2021-04-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-05-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-01-01, Off, NO
2,  2021-02-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-03-01, Off, No
2,  2021-04-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-05-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-01-01, On, No
3,  2021-02-01, Off, No
3,  2021-03-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-04-01, On, No
3,  2021-05-01, On, No
3,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
```

**Expected Result (12 rows)**

```
ID, DateYM, Status, Appointment
2,  2021-01-01, Off, NO
2,  2021-02-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-03-01, Off, No
2,  2021-04-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-05-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-01-01, On, No
3,  2021-02-01, Off, No
3,  2021-03-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-04-01, On, No
3,  2021-05-01, On, No
3,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
```

I was thinking to calculate the count between current month and first month and compare it with count of yes appointments and check if the count is same or not. But that is not 100% accurate.

Is there any Case statement or syntax which can exclude all the rows where appointment flag is yes for a given ID?

Comment: Okay so... You make a select query with the condition `where Appointment <> 'Yes'`... What do you want to do next?

Comment: I only want to exclude IDs if they have yes for all the months like in my example table all rows for ID=1 needs to be excluded

Comment: I understand now... I'll have to think a bit...

Comment: `Select t.*, Tt.num, ty.num from table t
Join (select id, count(date) num from table group by id) tt on (t.id=tt.id) join (select id, count(date) num from table where appointment = 'Yes' group by id) ty On (t.id=ty.id) where tt.num <> ty.num`